# finding boundaries of circle division by straight line

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a circle, I add a straight line that goes through the circle and intersects it at two points as well as intersects every previous line at one point.

I want to repeat this procedure (adding one straight line at a time) and figure out the points that make up the boundaries of the sections the circle is divided into.

For example the first time I do this (first line) it divides the circle into 2 pieces:
[image: circle divided in half]

When I add a second line it will divide each of these 2 pieces of the circle into 4 pieces:

[image]

When I add a third line it will divide the circle into 7 pieces:
[image]

What is an efficient algorithm to get these points?

Every time I add a line I can compute all the points that line intersects the circle and the other previous lines but I have to somehow figure out which regions these points are the boundary to

Comment: you have to find how many parts are formed or the intersection x-y position ?

Comment: I need to find how many parts are formed but also what are the x-y positions of the intersection points that form each of those parts

Comment: +1 because it looks interesting (Y)

Comment: this is actually very simple. Hint the circle is irrelevant and there is no need to find intersections between lines.

Comment: How else can I find the points that define the segments bounding each part other than by finding the intersection of the line with the circle and the other lines?

Comment: For each line you add, find the intersection points of that line with the circle, convert them to a radial angle from the origin of the circle, and insert that angle into a sorted list (or sort later if it's easier). At the end, the arcs between consecutive pairs of angles are your circle segments (plus the one final arc between the last angle in your list and the first)...

Comment: Thats a good idea. How do I keep track of the internal line segments in a systematic manner though (the ones defined by line-line intersection)?

Comment: Probably by splitting each into the individual segments and storing in some sort of graph structure. You'll then have to reconstruct the polygonal portions by following contours (e.g. the next segment is the one with the smallest angle relative to the current one) that can be calculated via cross products. Quadtree methods may be relevant, as well...

Comment: For each point build up a vector mapping which side of each line it lies on.  All points with the same vector lie in a common group.

Comment: i suppose I misread the question. Are the colored dots in the figure part of the problem?

Comment: @user2175783 I created an application that counts the different parts formed for you, what else do you need to know about the intersections

Comment: @george No the colored dots are not part of the problem just a visual indicator of the parts

Comment: @Amir I need to know also the boundaries of the parts (the line segments of each side of each part)

Comment: you are seeking to divide the region into non-overlapping polygons, with the (very slight) complication that some of the edges are circular arcs.  I could have sworn there was a question here on that topic but I cant find it.

Comment: @user2175783 my application currently do this for example: line from point 1 to point 3 intersect with line from point 0 to point 2 etc ... Total part formed are 18. Plus it will tell you all the lines created from which to point to which point

Comment: Please note that my application is actually a graph of a group of nodes forming the circle where you can link nodes to other to form a line

Comment: @george It is close, only that I dont have control over the line that will cut the circle into a few more parts (the line is picked dynamically)

Comment: @Amir Let me try your approach

Comment: @user2175783 Check my input / output, if it satisfies your question tell me so I post the code: http://justpaste.it/ft59

Comment: @Amir It seems your code gives how the points are connected but I think I would have to process the data some more. Ideally I would like an algorithm that would tell me: there are 6 parts/polygons and part 1 is formed by points [1,2,3], part 2 is formed by points [2,4], part 3 is formed by points [2,3,4,5]...

Comment: @user2175783 I'll see what I can do about this

Comment: One piece of advice i have, first consider a problem with a polygon boundary instead of the circle. After working out that algorithm go back and generalise it (or indeed depending on the precision you need you may get good results just discretising the circle to a few hundred edge polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand the question but:

1) line/line intersection is achieved by Cramer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

2) line/circle intersection is achieved by solving a quadratic equation http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

3) you can classify the points per region by considering all signs obtained when injecting the point coordinates in the parametric equation of the splitting lines (in other words, is the point on the left or on the right of the line); this gives you a binary labeling of all regions (some of the labels being impossible).
[image: Labeling]

You can also consider a ternary notation if you need to handle points known to be exactly on a line.

Comment: I know 1) and 2). The figures a slightly misleading in the sense that the points are there just for the visual indication of the different portions the circle is divided into. The problem is given an arbitrary straight line cutting the circle how to I compute the boundaries of each polygon into which the circle is divided.

Comment: You have two options: 1) the soft one, do not compute the boundaries, just label the regions in terms of the N signs respective to N lines - this is enough to know in what region you are. 2) the hard one: compute the line arrangement. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines)

Comment: +1 for the link.. but I do find it annoying that page makes the whole thing sound very complicated then fails to actually give the algorithm.

Comment: Arrangement of lines are difficult.